# moving a simple object

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I want to move an object, for example a box in 3D space, using ROS and visualize its movements in RVIZ. for this reason I wrote this node,

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include "geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Pose.h"
// publisher handles
ros::Publisher goal_pub;
void publish_goal()
{ 
  geometry_msgs::PoseStamped msg;
  msg.header.frame_id = "base_link";
  msg.pose.position.x += 2; 
  msg.pose.position.y = 20; 
  msg.pose.position.z = 50;   
  msg.pose.orientation.w = 0; 
  msg.pose.orientation.x = -2.0; 
  msg.pose.orientation.y = 0; 
  msg.pose.orientation.z = 0;  
  goal_pub.publish(msg);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "move_sphere");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Rate loop_rate(100);
    goal_pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>("pose", 1);
    while (ros::ok()) 
    {
      publish_goal();
      ros::spinOnce();
      loop_rate.sleep();
    }
}
```

but the object don't move. anyone can tell me what is the mistake in code.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122031/moving-a-simple-object/) by [robot_arm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2613/robot_arm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your code always publishes the same pos:

```
  geometry_msgs::PoseStamped msg;
```

msg contains default values( all zeros, false for bool )

```
  msg.pose.position.x += 2;
```

msg.pose.position.x is now (always) 0+2, i. e. 2.!! It does not increment (I guess that'd be your intention).

If you wish to do that define msg in global space, initialize at beginning of main and than increment in your loop like this:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include "geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Pose.h"
// publisher handles
ros::Publisher goal_pub;
geometry_msgs::PoseStamped msg;

void publish_goal()
{ 
  msg.pose.position.x += 2; 

  goal_pub.publish(msg);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

  msg.header.frame_id = "base_link";
  msg.pose.position.x = 2; 
  msg.pose.position.y = 20; 
  msg.pose.position.z = 50;   
  msg.pose.orientation.w = 0; 
  msg.pose.orientation.x = -2.0; 
  msg.pose.orientation.y = 0; 
  msg.pose.orientation.z = 0;  

    ros::init(argc, argv, "move_sphere");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Rate loop_rate(100);
    goal_pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>("pose", 1);
    while (ros::ok()) 
    {
      publish_goal();
      ros::spinOnce();
      loop_rate.sleep();
    }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-01-26**:
Nope, messages are initialized with default values (0.0 for floats, `false` for bools etc.) in their constructor. Other than that, this answer is correct (if you always re-initialize the msg, you'll always get the same results, so nothing moves).

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-01-26**:
@robot_arm: There are a couple more problems with your code, but they don't stop the object from moving: 1. the quaternion isn't valid; try orientation.x = 1.0. 2. You should set header.stamp = ros::Time::now(). 3. Do you really want to move the object by 2 * 100 meters a second? Try 0.02.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-01-27**:
Thanks Martin, you're right. I edited the answer accordingly.

**Comment by [robot_arm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2613/robot_arm/) on 2014-01-27**:
that's weird, I corrected the program and I did exaclty what you are suggested to. but nothing move.
when I type rostopic info /pose, I got the following information: rostopic info pose Type: geometry_msgs/PoseStamped Publishers: * /move_sphere (http://d:48494/) Subscribers: None it seems that there is no node subscribed to this topic, why ?